# SQL Query - restructure columns to rows

Tags: sqlite

I'm stuck! Wondering if someone can help me figure out an SQL query. I've got some data that looks like the following:

| Date | Country | Total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2022 | Australia | 1234 |
| 2/1/2022 | Australia | 5678 |
| 3/1/2022 | Australia | 1357 |
| 4/1/2022 | Australia | 2468 |
| 1/1/2022 | Italy | 1234 |
| 2/1/2022 | Italy | 5679 |
| 3/1/2022 | Italy | 1357 |
| 4/1/2022 | Italy | 2468 |

and I want to restructure it and create an output that looks like this"

| Date | Australia | Italy |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2022 | 1234 | 1234 |
| 2/1/2022 | 5678 | 5678 |

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Are you using Microsoft SQL Server, PostgreSQL, or MySQL?...and which version?

Comment: I have SQLiteStudio v3.3.3

Comment: So then you are using SQLite?...what version of SQLite (the database system, not the tool you use to query it)?

Comment: Where does *5678* in the Italy column on the desired result comes from ?

Comment: @ErgestBasha Probably a typo and they meant *567**9***

Comment: @J.D. it says v3.3.3, using it on a mac if that helps?

Comment: @ErgestBasha sorry yes thats a typo

Comment: @Ginger why not using [conditional aggregation](https://dbfiddle.uk/pMt6JJJs) ? I suggest using proper date datatype

Comment: @ErgestBasha thank you so much!!